# Python Selenium: Looping through href's embedded in <li> elements

Tags: python, html, selenium, web-scraping

I am parsing a web page with an organization like this:

```
<nav class="sidebar-main">
    <div class="sidebar">Found 3 targets</div>
        <ul><li><a href="#target1" class="current"><span>target1</span></a></li>
        <li><a href="#target2" ><span>target2</span></a></li>
        <li><a href="#target3"><span>target3</span></a></li></ul>
</nav>
```

My goal is to loop through each list element, clicking each one in the process:

```
sidebar = browser.find_element_by_class_name('sidebar-main')
elementList = sidebar.find_elements_by_tag_name("li")
for sample in elementList:
    browser.implicitly_wait(5)
    run_test1 = WebDriverWait(browser, 5).until(
        EC.presence_of_element_located((By.CLASS_NAME, 'sidebar-main'))
    )
    sample.click()
```

I keep getting the error:

```
Message: The element reference of <li> stale either the element is no 
longer attached to the DOM or the page has been refreshed.
```

Right now only one link is clicked, obviously selenium cannot locate subsequent elements upon page refresh, how do I get around this?

Comment: one link is clicked? are there more than one link inside that list?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Once you click on the first link, either navigation to new page happens or the page is refreshed. You need to keep track of the element list, find the list elements again and then click on the required element. If page is changed, then you need to navigate back to the original page as well.

You can try something like below

```
sidebar = browser.find_element_by_class_name('sidebar-main')
elementList = sidebar.find_elements_by_tag_name("li")
for i in range(len(elementList)):
    element = browser.find_element_by_class_name('sidebar-main').find_elements_by_tag_name("li")[i]
    element.click()
```